# execute a sequence of GET calls to an API wait and do some treatments on the results then give the result as argumant to another methode for a POST

Tags: rxjs, angular8, angular-promise

I am new to Angular and  i am facing some difficulties with a task. I have an array of IDs that i want to execute the same GET Call over. And for every GET call result i have to do some operations and then add the result of every operation to some arrays. I managed to find a way to do it correctly. But my problem is, i can't manage to wait for the final result to be ready (after all the GET calls are done and the operations too) before giving it as an argument to another method that will send it with a POST call.

the method where i do the GET calls and the operations over every call's result (the problem occurs when i am in the rollBackSPN condition).

```js
async getComponentIds(taskName: String, selectedComponents: IComponent[]) {
    const componentsId: number[] = [];
    const componentsWithoutParams: IComponent[] = [];
    let sendPortaPrecedente : boolean;

    if(taskName == "rollBackSPN"){
      from(selectedComponents).pipe(
        concatMap(component =>{
          return this.http.get<any>("Url"+component.idComponent).pipe(
            tap(val => {
              sendPortaPrecedente = true;

              for(const obj of val){
                if((obj.name == "z0bpqPrevious" && obj.value == null) || (obj.name == "datePortaPrevious" && obj.value == null) || (obj.name == "typePortaPrevious" && obj.value == null)){
                  sendPortaPrecedente = false;
                }
              }

              if(sendPortaPrecedente){
                componentsId.push(component.idComponent);
              }else{
                componentsWithoutParams.push(component);
              }
            }),
            catchError(err => {
              return of(err);
            })
          )
        })
      ).subscribe(val => {
        return { componentsId : componentsId, componentsWithoutParams : componentsWithoutParams, sendPortaPrecedente : sendPortaPrecedente};
      });

    }else{
      for (const component of selectedComponents) {
        componentsId.push(component.idComponent)
        return { componentsId : componentsId, componentsWithoutParams : componentsWithoutParams, sendPortaPrecedente : sendPortaPrecedente};
      }
    }
  }
```

The method where i pass the getComponentIds(taskName: String, selectedComponents: IComponent[]) result so it can be send with a POST call (again when i am in the rollBackSPN condition)

```js
executeTask(serviceIdSi: string, actionIdSi: string, actionClassName: string, componentName: string, taskName: string,
     componentsId: number[], componentsWithoutParams: IComponent[], sendPortaPrecedente: boolean): Observable<any> {
    
    const url = this.taskUrl + `?serviceId=${serviceIdSi}` + `&actionId=${actionIdSi}` + `&actionClassName=${actionClassName}`
      + `&componentName=${componentName}` + `&taskName=${taskName}`;
    
    
      if(taskName == "rollBackSPN"){

        if(sendPortaPrecedente && componentsWithoutParams.length == 0){
          return this.http.post<any>(url, componentsId);

        }else{

          let errMessage = "Some Error Message"

          for(const component of componentsWithoutParams){
            errMessage = errMessage + component.idComponent +"\n";
          }
          throw throwError(errMessage);

        }

      }else{
        return this.http.post<any>(url, componentsId);

      }
    
  }
```

Both these methods are defined in a service called TaskService.
And the service is called like this in a component UnitTaskButtonsComponent.

```js
async launchUnitTask() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.isClosed = false;
    this.appComponent.currentComponentIndex = this.componentIndex;
    let res = await  this.taskService.getComponentIds(this.unitTaskLabel, this.selectedComponents);
      
      
    this.taskService.executeTask(this.appComponent.currentService.identifiantSi,
      this.appComponent.currentAction.identifiantSi,
      this.appComponent.currentAction.className,
      this.selectedComponents[0].name,
      this.unitTaskLabel,
      res.componentsId,
      res.componentsWithoutParams,
      res.sendPortaPrecedente).subscribe(
      data => this.executeTaskSuccess(),
      error => this.executeTaskError());
  }
```

"res" properties are always undefined when it's a rollBackSPN task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that `getComponentIds` does not return a `Promise`. So `await`ing does not work. I would suggest to change `getComponentIds` so that it returns an `Observable` instead.

```js
getComponentIds(taskName: string, selectedComponents: IComponent[]) {
  //                        ^^^^^^ use string instead of String
  return forkJoin(
    selectedComponents.map((component) => {
      return this.http.get<any>("Url" + component.idComponent).pipe(
        map((val) => {
          let sendPortaPrecedente = true;

          for (const obj of val) {
            if (
              (obj.name == "z0bpqPrevious" && obj.value == null) ||
              (obj.name == "datePortaPrevious" && obj.value == null) ||
              (obj.name == "typePortaPrevious" && obj.value == null)
            ) {
              sendPortaPrecedente = false;
            }
          }

          return { component, sendPortaPrecedente }
        }),
        catchError((err) => of(err))
      );
    })
  ).pipe(
    map((result) => {
      const componentsId: number[] = [];
      const componentsWithoutParams: IComponent[] = [];

      for (const val of result) {
        if (val.sendPortaPrecedente) {
          componentsId.push(val.component.idComponent);
        } else {
          componentsWithoutParams.push(val.component);
        }
      }
      return { componentsId, componentsWithoutParams };
    })
  );
}
```

- Instead of using `concatMap`, let's use a `forkJoin`. The `forkJoin` allows sending all requests in parallel and returns the result in an array. But we have to pass in an array of `Observable`s. That's why we map over the `selectedComponents`.
- In the lower `map`, we can now get the complete result of the http calls in the `result` parameter. Here we do the processing of the data. I was not really sure how to handle the `sendPortaPrecedente`. You will have to fill that in.
- We simply return the whole `Observable`

```js
async launchUnitTask() {
  this.taskService
    .getComponentIds(this.unitTaskLabel, this.selectedComponents)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((res) => {
        this.taskService
          .executeTask(
            this.appComponent.currentService.identifiantSi,
            this.appComponent.currentAction.identifiantSi,
            this.appComponent.currentAction.className,
            this.selectedComponents[0].name,
            this.unitTaskLabel,
            res.componentsId,
            res.componentsWithoutParams,
            res.sendPortaPrecedente
          )
      })
    ).subscribe(
      (data) => this.executeTaskSuccess(),
      (error) => this.executeTaskError()
    );
}
```

In the `launchUnitTask` method, we don't use `await` anymore. Instead, we call `getComponentIds` and chain the call of `executeTask` with a `switchMap`.

Comment: first of all thank you for you answer! but the value of "component" isn't reachable in the scope of the lower map!

Comment: still the getComponentIds method is returning a void

Comment: @mhZakarya - oops, still missing the return statement

Comment: again thnks a lot, my good sir :)